# why session expire after some time in codeigniterand how to customized it?

Tags: codeigniter, session, chat

Hello I want to develop a chat application in CodeIgniter but there are lots of ajax call running in background when user logs in and chatting with each other.

Sometimes my ajax response displays login form HTML in chat form and i found out that my session getting expired. I do not know why its getting expired automatically so if someone can someone guide me to overcome this issue ?

It will be highly appreciated as well if someone guides me to use libraries or third part libraries (i.e Pusher for instance https://pusher.com/) which are helpful to built a better chat application using CodeIgniter.

Any help or suggestion would be highly appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Please visit this page on how to ask questions on SO: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0, accepted):

open this file in path : application\config\config.php and find out

$config['sess_expiration']

If you want to add some seconds then to session hold in set time